# Array Operations in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Why does the code below return 11 with this :- @myarray = ("Rohan");

Explaination i got was :- The expression $scalar x $num_times, on the other hand, returns a string containing $num_times copies of $scalar concatenated together string-wise. 
So it should give 10 not 11 ...
code is as below :-

```
print "test:\n";
@myarray = ("Rohan"); # this returns 11
##@myarray = ("Rohan","G"); this returns 22
@myarray2 = (@myarray x 2);
@myarray3 = ((@myarray) x 2); #returns Rohan,Rohan and is correct

print join(",",@myarray2,"\n\n");
print join(",",@myarray3,"\n\n");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What’s happening is that the `x` operator supplies scalar context not just to its right‐hand operand, but *also* to its left‐and operand as well — **unless** the LHO is surrounded by *literal* parens.

This rule is due to backwards compatibility with super‐ancient Perl code from back when Perl didn’t understand having a list as the LHO at all. This might be a v1 vs v2 thing, a v2 vs v3 thing, or maybe v3 vs v4. Can’t quite remember; it was a *very* long time ago, though.  Ancient legacy.

Since an array of N elements in scalar context in N, so in your scenario that makes `N == 1` and `"1" x 2 eq "11"`.

Comment: Thanks tchrist - i just figured that out when Eric commented about the scalar context - i commented above - but thanks for the clear explaination. This forum rocks

Comment: I prefer to explain it as ()x being a different operator than x (at least in list context).  It's not just the context of the LHO that changes, the operation is completely different (string repeat vs list repeat).  Unfortunately, they recently made the former syntax error `qw// x` work like ()x  (for arbitrary delimiters) which makes this a more awkward thing to explain.

Answer (score 4):

Perl is doing exactly what you asked.  In the first example, the array is in scalar context and returns its length.  this is then concatenated with itself twice.  In the second example, you have the array in list context and the `x` operator repeats the list.

Comment: Eric, sorry i got confused - scalar context will be a string which will return 5 - i did a @myarray x 2 - so the answer should be 10 - i am sorry if i got it wrong - could you please explain this?

Comment: Hey Eric - i got it - in scalar context its gonna count single string thats 1 and my answer is 11 it is correct - sorry and thanks